Five major sins (anantarika kamma) and how to mitigate them?
I started to learn and read Buddhist teachings, everything is very logical and compassionate. However, there is one thing that makes me wonder and confused: as far as I know, all evil karma can be repented and overcome, so why are there some particularly serious crimes that cannot be cured? For example, killing parents, causing Buddha to bleed, killing arahant, dividing the Sangha. Is there any way for them to repent to reduce their sins? In case they realize their mistakes, do they still have the opportunity to practice and attain liberation?

If the 5 major sins I just mentioned cannot be mitigated through repentance, then does it contradict this sutra?: "There's the case, headman, where a certain teacher holds this doctrine, holds this view: 'All those who take life are destined for a state of deprivation, are destined for hell. All those who steal... All those who indulge in illicit sex... All those who tell lies are destined for a state of deprivation, are destined for hell.' A disciple has faith in that teacher, and the thought occurs to him, 'Our teacher holds this doctrine, holds this view: "All those who take life are destined for a state of deprivation, are destined for hell." There are living beings that I have killed. I, too, am destined for a state of deprivation, am destined for hell.' He fastens onto that view. If he doesn't abandon that doctrine, doesn't abandon that state of mind, doesn't relinquish that view, then as if he were to be carried off, he would thus be placed in hell.
If someone accidentally creates the above evil karma without anger, will the result be different? I would be very grateful if someone could help me answer my question.


If someone accidentally creates the above evil karma without anger, will the result be different?
I assume that "accidentally" means it's not considered "killing".
The Vinaya specifies the elements of "killing" (i.e. which is one of the grave offences according to the monastic code):

This rule against intentionally causing the death of a human being is best understood in terms of five factors, all of which must be present for there to be the full offense.

Object: a human being, which according to the Vibhaṅga includes human fetuses as well, counting from the time consciousness first arises in the womb immediately after conception up to the time of death.
Intention: knowingly, consciously, deliberately, and purposefully wanting to cause that person’s death. “Knowingly” also includes the factor of—
Perception: perceiving the person as a living being.
Effort: whatever one does with the purpose of causing that person to die.
Result: The life-faculty of the person is cut as the result of one’s act.


It then gives various examples of accidental death.
Then adds that even hitting someone in anger, without intending to kill them, or even without thinking, would be "manslaughter" but not killing.
In context the killing must be intentional: deliberate.
You might like to read the whole section, it tries to explain or describe state of mind (or what I might call mens rea given I have a primarily Western vocabulary):

The Commentary seconds this point when it defines having made the decision as “having summoned up a reckless mind state, ‘crushing’ through the power of an attack.” The Sub-commentary does not explain crushing or attack here, but apparently they mean aggressively overcoming, through a brute act of will, any contrary or hesitant thoughts in the mind.

Remember it's said that "kamma is intention".

Maybe the topic isn't important, at least to me, personally I find it only very theoretical -- I can't imagine actually deliberately doing that, it's "unthinkable"!

It's discussed a little in this topic on Sutta Central:

Anantarika Kamma

Things I learn from that topic:

It's called "fixed or immediate karma", or "karma with a fixed result"

I think people assume this means, "fixed" means you'll definitely go to hell, and "immediate" means that will be in your very next life (unlike other karma which may or may not fruit over many subsequent lifetimes)
It may be Theravada doctrine that that is the meaning implied by the word "Anantarika Kamma".
Personally I like to know what the Pali word is. I imagine it (any word) might have a literal meaning, or that what is says literally might be what it means -- even though, other people have warned me in other contexts that "etymology" can be deceiving and may not reflect the modern meaning/usage of a word. I also assume a word may have a range of meanings or several meanings, perhaps a category instead of very specific.

There aren't many suttas which mention it (so it's possibly not "core" doctrine)

AN 6.93
AN 5.129


It's said to be impossible for "a person accomplished in view" to do that.


I'm not sure how to explain AN 6.93 -- I'd guess that it might be, not about the past, but that it's then impossible to do it in the future (they also have "virtue pleasing to the noble ones").

Is there any way for them to repent to reduce their sins?
One important point I would like to emphasize is that the idea of sins in the way it is defined by Christianity is quite alien to Buddhism. Especially, the concept that by repenting or asking for forgiveness from an almighty God, one’s sins would be forgiven. There are 2 reasons for this. One, there is no all-powerful god (who created the universe) in Buddhism. Two, wrongful or evil doings in Buddhism are a result of bad causes like greed, aversion and ignorance (of the fact that we are acting in ways that will hurt ourselves and others).
Overcoming a person’s greed, aversion and ignorance is neither within the purview of any god nor can it be overcome by any other beings other than the person themselves. Eliminating these bad causes is our sole responsibility as we are the source/originator of them. Thus, it might be a better idea to use the term unskillful (the words bad, evil or wrongful are often used too) acts instead of sins in Buddhism. They are unskillful acts because they give bad results that end up hurting/harming ourselves and others.
As far as what I understand about karma, once a karmic effect (good, bad or neutral) is present, it must run its course. The effects being felt/experienced can be reduced and there is a good answer on this in the forum so I will not touch this part.
I would like to stress three points here. First, a wise Buddhist would rather avoid unskillful acts in the first place as the amount of time, resources and efforts spent to reduce or negate bad karmic effects is disproportionately huge and there is no guarantee it will work. Second, the 5 major evil acts (the correct term is Anantarika-karma as mentioned by @ChrisW) generate such strong karmic effects that almost nothing (as far as I am aware of) can be done to reduce their effects (forget about negation). One such example is the story of King Ajatasattu where it is said that this king is destined for the hell realms after his death due to committing patricide. In DN02, the Buddha declared that had the king not killed his father, he would had attained the fruit of stream-winner (sotāpanna) after hearing the comprehensive teaching by the Buddha on that occasion. This is also a good example of how very bad karma can hinder one’s spiritual progress.
The last point is that repenting is a complicated term that involved guilt (or remorse), regret and a resolution to atone for one’s wrong doings. In Buddhism, regrets are not seen as helpful as one cannot undo past wrong actions. However, guilt (connected to one’s past actions or behaviour) as well as shame (associated to one’s weaknesses that caused the wrongful behaviour) can be useful to motivate one to reflect on why one did those bad actions. Thus, assisting in understanding the root causes of one’s behaviour and helping in preventing recidivism. The mental pain of guilt and shame in addition to the cost (i.e. time, effort and resources) of atoning and remedying one’s wrongs can be a powerful motivation to never repeat the same mistakes ever again. Thus, it might be better to only keep those parts of repenting that is useful and discard the parts (such as regrets) that are not.
If someone accidentally creates the above evil karma without anger, will the result be different?
No, bad effects/results would still be experienced eventually. Anger (under aversion) is just one of the 3 root causes (the others being greed and ignorance) of unskillful actions in Buddhism. So, if one committed Anantarika-karma as a result of greed or ignorance, the same bad karmic effects will still be experienced.

Firstly, karma is based on intention. If something was done unintentionally, there's no karma.
Secondly, this is not really a sin to be judged and/or forgiven by a God or gods.
Exerting oneself in the performance of intentional karma leaves a mark or effect on our minds that bears consequences. Please see SN42.3.
Scientific studies have shown how soldiers returning from the battlefield after killing many enemy combatants (and maybe also civilians) suffer from PTSD. They have remorse.
Killing other humans, knowing that they wouldn't want others to do it unto them, is a cause of serious karma with serious consequences on the mind, and their lives.
Despite that, stories like Angulimala shows that serial killers can become fully liberated, only if they did not commit the gravest of karma, the anantarika-kamma.
The anantarika-kamma leaves such an indelible stain of defilement on their minds for that lifetime, that those minds would never be able to comprehend the Dhamma in a way that allows it to reach stream entry. Those minds are too damaged.

"Endowed with these six qualities, a person is incapable of alighting
on the lawfulness, the rightness of skillful mental qualities even
when listening to the true Dhamma. Which six?
"He has killed his mother; he has killed his father; he has killed an
arahant; he has, with corrupt intent, caused the blood of a Tathagata
to flow; he has caused a split in the Sangha; or he is a person of
dull discernment, slow & dull-witted.
AN 6.87

That doesn't mean that there is nothing that they can do. They can resolve to keep the five precepts with heedfulness (appamāda), and live a virtuous life.

Do not disregard merit,
thinking it will have no consequence.
Just as falling drops of water
fill up a bucket,
a sage becomes full of merit
collecting it little by little.
Dhp 122

